# C++ ignores if statement

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Sometimes visual C++ ignores an if condition and never enters it!
In debug mode I see the value of the conditional expression is true but C++ ignores it!

like this:

```
if (childrens.at(j)->rules.size() > tempMax) {
    tempMax = childrens.at(j)->rules.size();
}
```

it works correctly  when I change it to this :

```
tempInt = childrens.at(j)->rules.size();
if (tempInt > tempMax) {
    tempMax = tempInt;
}
```

Why, and what is the fix?

Comment: try closing optimizations. maybe helps

Comment: maybe it's a type issue. Are the types of `tempInt`, `tempMax`, and `size()` all the same?

Comment: @ataman How could that possibly help?

Comment: First, how do you know the condition is true? Second, how do you know the if statement isn't being executed? I'd be willing to bet that you're mistaken on one of those two assumptions.

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @juanchopanza i encountered 2 times in last 6 years that optimizations cause a different logic to work. just a suggestion. exact reason may depend on anything but optimization bugs are real.

Comment: @ataman That isn't helping. That is making buggy code behave differently.

Comment: @ataman Chances are it was undefined behavior caused by a bug _you_ introduced rather than a compiler bug.

Comment: @juanchopanza i say that there is a code that works in desired logic when optimization level is 0 but does not if not. then I say there is a bug about optimization. it is a software in the end. what do you mean by "That is making buggy code behave differently."

Comment: @ataman It is much more likely that it is a bug in your code, not the optimization. Optimizations (other than copy elision) are not allowed to change observable behaviour.

Comment: @juanchopanza is not it a software? how do you guarantee that?

Comment: OP: Consider [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max). No need for an `if` loop that "c++ ignores" (which I doubt is the case)

Comment: @Captain Obvlious what you say  is ofcourse more probable. but finding the root cause if i am right is really hard. and it is very easy to try.

Comment: @KeithThompson I understand it by step by step debugging ! and check all value and ...

Comment: @Tas My program work correctly when I use second figure that written above that implies that if logic work and program need it.

Comment: But you could remove the `if` statement completely: `tempMax = std::max(childrens.at(j)->rules.size(), tempMax);`

Comment: Sadly the debugger isn't always right. I've made an ass of myself on SO before because the debugger and the compiler had very different interpretations. I don't know what `rules` is but in most classes in the standard library, size() returns an unsigned value. Compare that against an int and you will have a bad time. Stuff that unsigned value into an temporary int, test that int, and you will get a very different result. I'd start by cranking warnings up to the most pedantic level MSVS allows and rebuild. There might be a revelation in the warnings.

Comment: @user4581301 is onto something. My guess would be, `tempMax` is negative; perhaps you set it to -1 initially. When compared to an unsigned value, it itself gets converted to unsigned and wraps around to a very large number.

Answer (score 0):

Add this else to your if:

```
if (childrens.at(j)->rules.size() > tempMax) {
    tempMax = childrens.at(j)->rules.size();
}else{
    string inputCheck;
    cout<<"children."<<j<<".rules."<<childrens.at(j)->rules.size()<<" > "<<tempMax;
    cout<<"\nMy if - statement isn't working (Press Enter/Return to continue): ";
    cin.ignore(256,'\n');
    getline(cin,inputCheck);
}
```

And see what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

@user4581301 told problem and I checked it and he is right.

In this code

```
if (childrens.at(j)->rules.size() > tempMax) {
tempMax = childrens.at(j)->rules.size();
}
```

`rule.size()` return unsigned and temp `tempMax` is `int`. that it's initial value is `INT_MIN` , optimizer ignore this because unsigned int. always bigger than negative , but after entering in if body `tempMax` became positive and I don't know why optimizer ignores it!

I write this new program

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    
    vector<bool> a;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        a.push_back(true);
    }
    
    int tempMax = INT_MIN;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        if (a.size() > tempMax)
        {
            tempMax = a.size();
        }
    }
    
    cout << tempMax << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and ***output*** is -2147483648

and after changing type of `a.size()` to `(int)a.size()` it fixed:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    
    vector<bool> a;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        a.push_back(true);
    }
    
    int tempMax = INT_MIN;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((int)a.size() > tempMax)
        {
            tempMax = a.size();
        }
    }
    
    cout << tempMax << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also worth considering is `size_t tempMax = 0;` and getting rid of the cast. Unless you need a catch for having no vectors at all, there are never going to be less than 0 elements.